# Adding substring from a textbox to a listbox

Tags: c#

I have a textbox in which the user enters some string. Now, I extract a substring from the main string and display it into a listbox.

For example:
 If the user enters: SELECT A1,A2,A3 FROM TABLE1
 then I need A1,A2 and A3 as separate items of my listbox.

I am able to do that easily, however there's a small problem that is occurring.

As soon as the user finishes typing the word "FROM", the values get added to the listbox and if the user types anything after "FROM"(even a space), the values get added again.

I need the values only once. What am I missing? Please help

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string substr;
        string str = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=.\s+).+?(?=\s+from)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        try
        {
            if (m.Success)
            {
                substr = m.Value;
                string[] sub = substr.Split(',');
                foreach (string x in sub)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(x);
                }
            }
        finally
        {
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textBox1_TextChanged` Fires on every character being written or removed from the `TextBox` when the user is typing. You can clear the `ListBox` every time you want to do this action (The very first action of your above method) :

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

I really suggest that you go with another approach, executing a somehow heavy logic on frequent events like `TextChanged` is not a very good idea. Probably you need a List and each time you compare the results and add only the new ones. Or you can execute this logic on a button click or maybe when the text box loses focus.

Anyway, unless you experience bad performance, you can keep on doing what you doing now.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this operation in enter press event in textbox, so user first insert whole text then if he/she press enter button then operation will perform

```
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                string substr;
                string str = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=.\s+).+?(?=\s+from)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
               try
               {
                   if (m.Success)
                   {
                       substr = m.Value;
                       string[] sub = substr.Split(',');
                       foreach (string x in sub)
                       {
                           listBox1.Items.Add(x);
                       }
                   }
               }
               finally
               {
                   listBox1.EndUpdate();
               }
            }
  }
```

and you can perform this operation using a button click as well. Same logic will work there too